# Are these two modules isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, and let $A=k[x]$.

Consider the two $A$-modules $A\otimes_{k} A$ and $Hom_{k}(A,A)$.

Are these two $A$-modules isomorphic?

Edit: I was explained that they are different.

I wonder if someone can please tell me where does the following proof that they are isomorphic break down:

Step 1:
$Hom_k(K[x],K[x]) \cong Hom_k(k[x],Hom_{k[x]}(k[x],k[x]))$

Step 2:
$Hom_k(k[x],Hom_{k[x]}(k[x],k[x])) \cong Hom_{k[x]}(k[x]\otimes_{k} k[x],k[x]) $

Step 3:

$Hom_{k[x]}(k[x]\otimes_{k} k[x],k[x]) \cong Hom_{k[x]}(k[x]\otimes_{k} k[x],Hom_{k[x]\otimes_k k[x]}(k[x],k[x]\otimes_k k[x]))$

Step 4:
$Hom_{k[x]}(k[x]\otimes_{k} k[x],Hom_{k[x]\otimes_k k[x]}(k[x],k[x]\otimes_k k[x])) \cong
Hom_{k[x]\otimes_k k[x]}(k[x]\otimes_k k[x],k[x]\otimes_k k[x])
$

Step 5:
$Hom_{k[x]\otimes_k k[x]}(k[x]\otimes_k k[x],k[x]\otimes_k k[x]) \cong Hom_{k[x]}(k[x],k[x])\otimes_k Hom_{k[x]}(k[x],k[x])$

And the latter is just  $= k[x]\otimes_k k[x]$.

I cannot find the problem.

Comment: Hint: Consider the dimensions as $k$-vectorspaces.

Comment: Well, the left hand side has countable dimension. But what is the dimension of the right hand side?

Comment: The righthand side contains $Hom_k(A,k)$ which has uncountable dimension.